# Want to allocate more memory to Tomcat but catalina.sh is missing

Tags: java, tomcat8

I am running a Tomcat8 server on linux (RedHat). The machine it runs on has a total of 15GB Ram of which i want to allocate 11GB to the tomcat server. Currently it only has 3.3GB avaialable for use.

I have openjdk 64 bit installed.

I am trying to set `CATALINA_OPTS` to `-Xms512M -Xmx11g` and the `JAVA_OPTS` to `-d64 -Xms256m -Xmx12g`.

I found several how-to's saying something about a `setenv.sh` or `catalina.sh` both of which I cannot find: neither under `tomcat8/bin`, `catalina_home` or `catalina_base` which both point to `/root`.

So how do I increase available memory for my Tomcat server?

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems that catalina.sh is either no longer existent in the latest tomcat release or it has something to do with the fact that i am using a amazon vm and they have some kind of modified tomcat8 distribution what i would doubt.

Solution:
under `usr/share/tomcat8/conf/` there is a `tomcat8.conf` file.
Adding the row `JAVA_OPTS="-Xms1g -Xmx12g"` did the trick.

**UPDATE:**
Please check the comments below this post

Comment: I can confirm this is the only way I've found to increase memory settings on Tomcat8 hosted on AWS.  Not sure if it's a Tomcat8 or an AWS thing.

Comment: It's much better to user CATALINA_OPTS for server settings. JAVA_OPTS is also used for shutdown.sh, which doesn't require 1GiB of RAM on start just to send shutdown message.

Answer (score 1):

In distributions such as RedHat the standard Tomcat structure is dispersed in different locations and the main catalina.sh is indeed not present.

There are two configuration files you may find.  Assuming Tomcat 8, you'll find:

- `/etc/tomcat8/tomcat8.conf` - this is the master file
- `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat8` - this is per service file which inherits from the above.

This split is designed so that you can have multiple Tomcat instances running which share some settings and have distinct settings for the 1st/2nd/3rd instance.

If you want to change the location of the software, for example, normally this would be shared so you would change `/etc/tomcat8/tomcat8.conf`, but if you want to change command line arguments (to pass context to a Tomcat instance) or change memory of the particular instance, you'd use `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat8`.  You second instance of tomcat could be named `tomcat8b` in which case its configuration file would be `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat8b`.

If you have no intention of running a second instance, then change either file.

Comment: I've been looking to find info on the file `/etc/sysconfig/tomcat8` you have mentioned. Are there any official docs that provide more info?

Answer (score -3):

catalina.sh is under tomcat/bin

Comment: that's what i thought, However it is not there. ``$CATALINA_HOME`` also points to / and there is neither a tomcat nor a catalina.sh folder/file under ``/bin/``-folder. However tomcat itself works just fine.